# CGI python doesn't print when call getvalue

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json

I send a json with ajax jquery and I want to print the data in a txt file with python:
client:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#clickme').click(function(){
                alert('Im going to start processing');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.py",
                    type: "post",
                    datatype:"json",
                    data: {'key':'value','key2':'value2'},
                    success: function(response){
                        alert(response.message);
                        alert(response.keys);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="clickme"> click me </button>
</body>
```

Server:

```
import json`import cgi`
fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
out_file = open("test.txt","w")
for k in fs.keys(): 
    out_file.write(fs.getvalue(k))
```

but the code doesn't print anything

Comment: What's the error in the log? For one, you don't use the `sys` import. Plus you don't `import cgi`.

Comment: I'm sorry but i forgot to paste import cgi. The errori is that the code dosen't print anything

Answer (score 0):

To help debug the issue, write the entire environment to a file.  This will be all the GET args.

1. change `'post'` to `'get'` in your Ajax code
2. try code like this (untested):

   import os
   with open('/tmp/output.log','a') as outf:
      outf.write( repr(os.environ) )
      outf.write('\n')